# does Ubuntu use a different unicode?

Tags: keyboard-layout, unicode

I use Persian letter ۀ (U+06C0) so many times, so I tried to assign a simple key for it.
I opened  "/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ir" and changed a  key which I never use, like this:

```
key <AC07> { [ Arabic_teh,      0x000006C0,                VoidSymbol   ] };
```

but instead of ۀ it types ю which is U+044E (Unicode 0x0000044E)

I can't understand why. Are Unicode-32 codes different in Ubuntu?! I bet no but I don`t  where is my mistake.
How can I change my AC07 key to type ۀ (U+06C0) instead of ю (U+044E)

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 23.10 with IR keyboard layout (Persian)
I put the line mentioned above in the file "/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ir"
in line 74 under the part called     // Persian letters and symbols

Comment: Given the line you showed, you need to press <Shift>+AC07 to make it type ۀ .

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson yes, that is the line I wrote and it should do that, but it doesn`t. it types the other character and I can`t find why.

Comment: Then please edit your question and tell us which keyboard layout you are using and exactly where you put that line.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  Thank you very much, I appreciate the time. I did the edit.

Comment: No there is only 1 unicode ;-) Try `key <AC07> { [ Arabic_beh,  Arabic_hamzaunderalef, VoidSymbol ] };`

Comment: Here is an example of a persian keyboard layout. https://gist.github.com/sijad/d63afe9c2955ad87e91792a9ea97ae19   Probably best to copy the 1st section over into your version

Comment: @Rinzwind  That's the default code. I don't use hamzaunderalef (U+0625) at all, and I need ۀ (U+06c0) hundreds of times per hour. So I want to change AC07 from the default to the code I mentioned.

Comment: sorry I thought I was on the right track :(  and the char is not in the list in the link? sorry

Comment: @Rinzwind I appreciate your try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the behavior on my own Ubuntu 22.04. Then I replaced `0x000006C0` with `0x10006C0` and voilà — <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AC07</kbd> now results in the ۀ character.

Can't really explain it, but looking at other Unicode entries in the XKB files, I see many entries starting with `0x100`.

Comment: WOW! it  DOES work for me. thank you very much for the time and effort, it will save a huge amount of time for me.